# run shell commands from python, and How to store result in a file(text or excell or csv etc..)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(['nmap', '-sn', '***.***.*.*'])
out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)
```

THE O/p as BELOW:----> IS MUST BE STORE INTO TEXT FILE

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-12-11 04:26 *****n Standard Time
Nmap scan report for ***.***.*.*
Host is up (0.00s latency).
MAC Address: **:**:**:**:**:BF (***** *****(******)Co.)
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.82 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is sending the output you want to the screen. To send it to a file instead, change this:

```
print(out)
```

to

```
with open("my_output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    print(out, file=outfile)
```

Comment: 'None' is storing

Comment: Whatever you see in the file is what is in the variable `out`. Add back your original `print` call (so that the output goes to screen *and* file) and use that to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to
>   create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get anything
>   other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE
>   and/or stderr=PIPE too.

So in your case you should write:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['nmap', '-sn', '***.***.*.*'], stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check

```
import subprocess
out = subprocess.check_output(['nmap', '-sn', '***.***.*.*'])
with open("./my.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Comment: f.write(out)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'